# What do you call fake interviews that have been scripted

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call those fake interviews which are conducted according to a specific script, perhaps, against your honest beliefs?

Comment: I think you need to be a little clearer, perhaps provide examples of what you're talking about. As your question stands, it's likely to be closed as "not clear what you're asking."

Comment: Wouldn't that be a *scripted* (or perhaps *pre-scripted*) interview?  (I've heard "scripted interview" numerous times.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean a [fixed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fixed) interview:

> - arranged in advance privately or dishonestly: a fixed race.

Referring specifically to a script; *scripted*, written as for a film  or a play:

India TV journalist quits over ‘scripted’ Modi [interview](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-others/india-tv-journalist-quits-over-scripted-modi-interview/) -

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a *canned interview*, to me.

> Adjective: canned  kand
>
> 1. Recorded for broadcast
>
>    "canned laughter";
>
>    - transcribed
>
> -- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=canned)

There is often a connotation of falseness for something that is canned in the sense of recorded: it is not live and does not seem natural. Canned laughter, which is the example given here by the first definition of *canned*, is often considered phony.

Comment: Can you explain your answer in this context?  The only definitions of canned that I could find did not seem relevant.

Comment: @ThunderGuppy: Done. It is the first meaning given in the reference I posted.